# User Authentication: Correct ruby syntax for determining the correct user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make sure a user can see their one profile, but no one else's.  I thought this would work, but it's not.

```
  def show
    if current_user 
      if current_user.id != User.find(params[:id]) 
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @title = @user.name
      end if 
   else
      redirect_to root_path   
    end
  end
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to compare `id`s instead of trying to compare one id with a `User` class:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if current_user.id == @user.id
  @title = @user.name
end
```

But your best bet might actually be to give something like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) a shot. It can greatly simplify permission-related tasks!

Comment: Thanks!  I'll checkout CanCan.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You should change it to this.

```
def show
    if current_user != User.find(params[:id]) 
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @title = @user.name
    else
      redirect_to root_path   
    end
  end
```

The reason why what you are doing won't work is because you are basically asking if the user.id is equal to a user object. You should be asking if the current_user object is equal to the User.find(id), since that will return a User object. Hope that helps.